# How to cover RowMapper block in junit testing by mock?

Tags: java, spring-boot, jdbc, junit

I try to mock one query in that I'm using rowmapper block as output. I created a block for `new RowMapper<Object>() {}`, inside block I set the values in a map and returning that map. The code is running successfully but in code coverage I'm not able to cover code inside RowMapper block.

I tried to use `thenAnswer` to cover that block but getting exception

```
jdbcTempCPA.query(sql, new Object[] { orderNo, orderNo }, new RowMapper<Object>() {
                @Override
                public Object mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
                    ret.put("GetValue",
                            CommonUtil.correctNullString(rs.getString("SELECTED")));
                    ret.put("Indicator"
                            CommonUtil.correctNullString(rs.getString("ADVISORY_INDICATOR")));
                    return ret;
                }
            });
```

and here is junit code to cover above code

```
Mockito.when(jdbcTemplateMock.query(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(Object[].class),Matchers.<RowMapper<Map<String, String>>>any())).thenReturn(ret);
```

Comment: _"but getting exception" What exception? Please post the stacktrace. Also provide a [mcve] not just snippets of code.